# passing arguments without commandline

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a module which accepts arguments from the command line, let's call that module `A`.

I would like to execute `A` from another module - `B`, so that `B` will set `A`'s arguments-

without executing `A` as a separate process.

Any way to do that?

Comment: No pretty way if A doesn't cooperate (e.g. by having a `main(argv)` function). I presume you can't change it to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how module `A` takes it's arguments. If it *only* looks at `sys.argv` and has no `__main__` test, then you could alter `sys.argv`:

```
sys.argv[1:] = ['arg1', 'arg2']
```

then import module `A`.

However, if you are writing `A` yourself, use a function, called from a `__main__` test instead:

```
def main(*args):
    # main code for module

if __name__ == '__main__`:
    import sys
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

then you can import `A` and call `main()` directly:

```
import A
A.main('arg1', 'arg2')
```

Note that if module `A` is not your own, and it *does* have a `__main__` test, but does all the work in that `if __name__ == '__main__':` suite, then you are sunk and have to reproduce that code.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: well, let's see if being the fastest counts for that much. :-P

Answer (score 2):

Just define a main method in your script so that it can be run from both the command line and as a module:

```
def main(arg1, arg2):
    # All your code goes here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Then you can do either:

```
$ a.py x y
```

Or

```
>>> import a
>>> a.main('x', 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.argv[1:] = ["My Arguments","other Args"] #dont replace [0] ...since it can let you know which script was actually executed ...

import A
A.run() #or whatever
```

I think will work ... not really recommended but ....